# Are Github/Azure container registries "image names" different than a dockerhub "repository?"

Tags: docker, github, dockerhub, azure-container-registry

A bit confused about how dockerhub works compared to github container registry (ghcr) and azure container registry (acr). For both ACR and GHCR, I create an "image" under my namespace. So I can use the following tag and then push successfully

`docker image tag existingImage ghcr.io/mynamespace/image/name/that/has/slashes:tag1`

Dockerhub docs refer to part after the namespace as the "repository" and seem to have extra restrictions such as no slashes.

`docker image tag existingImage docker.io/mynamespace/repositorynamewithnoslashes:tag1`

Except for the extra naming restrictions, are the "image" and "repository" the same? I'm trying to write some code that helps users build an image and push it for them, but I was intending to have slashes in the produced image name. Noticed it fails on Dockerhub and trying to understand if there are other differences.

Answer (score 2):

You can have many images in a single repository. A *repository* refers to a named path that can contain multiple images. An *image* typically refers to a specific image within a repository with a particular manifest/digest and usually a specific tag like `latest`.

The nomenclature for these terms originates from the *Open Container Initiative (OCI)* specifications (specifically, the [image](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/releases/tag/v1.0.1) and [distribution](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/releases/tag/v1.0.0) specs) which are vendor-neutral.

Comment: A more "friendly" doc can be found on Docker doc for image tag: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/ - namely, an image name nomenclature is `[REGISTRY/][NAMESPACE/]REPOSITORY[:TAG]`